Azure SQL timeouts on specific queries - sensitive index
We use Azure SQL Server and EF Core 6 to access this database.  For the below abstracted model, we use the queries as included below the model.  Performance is almost always good, until it's not and then the server query will timeout (30 seconds). Inline edit: the timeouts only occur to tenants with a lot of data/projects and not others. From that point each and every query will time out for these tenants, until we rebuild or reorganize the indexes.  After which performance is fully restored again.
We are taking a few perspectives on solving the issue, including pre-emptive rebuilding the relevant indexes.  In addition, could we re-write the query for better performance as the performance issue seems very specific to this query (at least he issue has not surfaced elsewhere)?
public class Invoice : OwnedByBase, ITransaction<LineItem>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
//...
}

var invoices = await dbContext.Invoices
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Include(i => i.LineItems)
    .Where(i => i.CompanyGuid == companyGuid)
    .Where(i => i.LineItems.Any(idet => idet.ProjectGuid == projectGuid))
    .ToListAsync();

resulting SQL query:
-- ...
FROM [Invoices] AS [i]
WHERE (([i].[OwnedBy] = @__ef_filter__tenantId_0) AND ([i].[CompanyGuid] = @__companyGuid_0)) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [LineItems] AS [i0]
    WHERE ([i].[Id] = [i0].[InvoiceId]) AND ([i0].[ProjectGuid] = @__projectGuid_1))
ORDER BY [i].[Id]

There is a global query filter on OwnedBy, which has an index.  CompanyGuid and ProjectGuid also have an index.

This almost sounds like a parameter sniffing problem. Do you have uneven distributions of values in your table (assuming good/relevant indexing)? Have you tried adding a RECOMPILE to your OPTION clause on the query to see if that avoids the issue?

Have you looked at the query plans? I'm guessing it's either building statistics which is why it gets stalled, or that it perhaps joins on InvoiceID ahead of time. But hard to say, how many invoices are there per companyGuid and how many Lines are there per ProjectGUID. Index won't help you if there are way too many rows per each selection

@ThomA I have not tried the RECOMPILE option.  It sounds like @siggermannen is suspecting something similar.  We have tenants (OwnedBy) with little data and some with loads.  Some CompanyGuid will have a hand full of projects, while others have thousands.  The number of LineItems is typically comparable per ProjectGuid from a few dozens up to a thousand or so.

Try with this extension WithRecompile to ensure that this is not Parameter Sniffing.

Thanks all, we'll investigate the parameter sniffing problem since our data is probably considered not evenly distributed.  I also added a note to the fact that not all tenants are affected by the timeouts since that now seems more relevant than I expected.

You mentioned your indexes, but it was not clear whether you had separate indexes for each listed column or combined indexes. When filter conditions are applied involving multiple columns, having a single index covering all of those columns is usually preferred over separate indexes, since SQL Server can usually only make use of one index at a time. A combined index on InvoicesI(OwnedBy, CompanyGuid) will be much more performant than separate indexes for each column. The same goes for LineItems(InvoiceId, ProjectGuid).

Indexes are going to be of limited use on GUID columns if you are using typical Guid.NewGuid() or TSQL NewId(). In large datasets these will lead to a lot of fragmentation in the index. AzureSQL supports NewSequentialId() and there are matching implementations for C# which can significantly improve index performance. Regular index maintenance is recommended when working with UUIDs, sequential or especially non-sequential.

@StevePy - While having a GUID as the PK/clustered-index scatters the data so that you don't get the data localization that you get with sequential IDs, a properly defined index (allowing a seek and key lookup) still provides a huge performance gain over having no index at all (necessitating table scans). Analogy: You need 3 related books from the library. With sequential IDs you find that all three are located on the same shelf. With GUIDs they are located on different floors, rows, and shelves, but you know where they are. With no index, you have to walk the isles and check each title.

I didn't say they were useless, just limited. Index fragmentation slows down reads as well as inserts so my advice is that if you don't need random UUIDs, consider sequential ones to limit the impact, and in either case schedule regular index maintenance jobs to re-organize the indexes. The index in your library is a cabinet with up to 3 drawers and 1000 cards per drawer. With UUIDs when you add a book you can end up adding an entirely new drawer or even a new cabinet to the left or right when there was plenty of room in the existing ones.
